# How can I write a csv file with multiple header lines with pandas to_csv()?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Consider a data frame with a `date` column as an index and three columns `x`, `y` and `z` with some observations. I want to write the contents of this data frame to a .csv file. I know I can use `df.to_csv` for this, however, I would like to add a second header line with the units. In this example, the desired .csv file would look something like this:

```
date,x,y,z  
(yyyy-mm-dd),(s),(m),(kg)  
2014-03-12,1,2,3  
2014-03-13,4,5,6  
...
```

Comment: Maybe you could just write the first line using normal python output (file.write()),and then write the data frame with the units line as the header under that. (Not sure if this works or not, but maybe a way to do it)

Comment: How is that different from inserting a new row with your "second" header at the beginning?

Comment: @Ben: How can I do that with a string for the index (keep in mind I have a datetime-index)? I tried using `df.loc()`, but apparently I get the syntax wrong (I always get the error `ValueError: unsafe appending to index of type DatetimeIndex with a key yyyy-mm-dd`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't produce the exact output in your example, but it's close. You can use multi-index columns to store the second header (the units) with the column labels:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
...     zip(['date', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
...         ['(yyyy-mm-dd)', '(s)', '(m)', '(kg)']))
>>> data = [['2014-03-12', 1, 2, 3],
...         ['2014-03-13', 4, 5, 6]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
>>> df
          date   x   y    z
  (yyyy-mm-dd) (s) (m) (kg)
0   2014-03-12   1   2    3
1   2014-03-13   4   5    6
```

Storing the second header this way allows your columns to keep the correct type (e.g., column `x` should be an integer type):

```
>>> df.dtypes
date  (yyyy-mm-dd)    object
x     (s)              int64
y     (m)              int64
z     (kg)             int64
dtype: object
```

If you had stored the second header as a *row* in the `DataFrame`, your column `dtypes` would become `object`, which you probably don't want.

Writing the `DataFrame` in CSV format produces something very similar to your example:

```
>>> df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
>>> !cat out.csv
date,x,y,z
(yyyy-mm-dd),(s),(m),(kg)
,,,
2014-03-12,1,2,3
2014-03-13,4,5,6
```

The only difference is the extra line of commas, which is how pandas separates multi-row headers from the actual rows of data. This allows the CSV file to be read back into an equivalent `DataFrame`:

```
>>> df2 = pd.read_csv('out.csv', header=[0, 1])
>>> df2
          date   x   y    z
  (yyyy-mm-dd) (s) (m) (kg)
0   2014-03-12   1   2    3
1   2014-03-13   4   5    6
```

Note: I found a lot of this information scattered throughout [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24372993/3776794).