# Error: object of type 'zip' has no len() after adding extra header by using zip

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe

> I try to follow this link [pandas dataframe with 2-rows header and export to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372993/pandas-dataframe-with-2-rows-header-and-export-to-csv) in order for me to created extra header without remove the original header, below is my coding:
>
> ```
> df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((zip(df.columns,[uniquevaluesfirstcolumnww, '', uniquevaluesfirstcolumnww1, ' ',uniquevaluesfirstcolumnww2, '  '])))
> ```
>
> I get the error such as this:  **object of type 'zip' has no len()**
>
> Anyone have any idea? even though I try to add list before zip but fail also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is `zip` return `object` in `python 3`, so need convert to `list`:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((list(zip(df.columns,[uniquevaluesfirstcolumnww, '', uniquevaluesfirstcolumnww1, ' ',uniquevaluesfirstcolumnww2, '  ']))))
```

But is seems you need [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
cols = list('abcdef')
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,1,1,1]], columns=cols)
print (df)
   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  1  1  1  1  1

uniquevaluesfirstcolumnww = 'r'
uniquevaluesfirstcolumnww1 = 's'
uniquevaluesfirstcolumnww2 = 't'
vals = [uniquevaluesfirstcolumnww, '', 
        uniquevaluesfirstcolumnww1, ' ',
        uniquevaluesfirstcolumnww2, '  ']
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns, vals])
print (df)
   a  b  c  d  e  f
   r     s     t   
0  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

---

If columns have `MultiIndex` also:

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a','b','c'], ['x','y']])
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,1,1,1]], columns=cols)
print (df)
   a     b     c   
   x  y  x  y  x  y
0  1  1  1  1  1  1

uniquevaluesfirstcolumnww = 'r'
uniquevaluesfirstcolumnww1 = 's'
uniquevaluesfirstcolumnww2 = 't'
vals = [uniquevaluesfirstcolumnww, '', 
        uniquevaluesfirstcolumnww1, ' ',
        uniquevaluesfirstcolumnww2, '  ']
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns.get_level_values(0), 
                                        df.columns.get_level_values(1), 
                                        vals])
print (df)
   a     b     c   
   x  y  x  y  x  y
   r     s     t   
0  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: I get this error **unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'** after I add list

Comment: and another solutions? what return `print (vals)` ?

Comment: and what return `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: Still show me the same error **unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'**

Comment: I add some sample, it can help I hope.