# python pandas dataframe write multi row header

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas.excelwriter

data1

```
A  B  C  D  E   <--- columns
a  b  c  d  e
a  b  c  d  e
a  b  c  d  e


result what i want

A  B  C  D  E <--- columns
A  B  C  D  E <--- columns
A  B  C  D  E <--- columns
a  b  c  d  e
a  b  c  d  e
a  b  c  d  e
```

I searched for this one and it finally failed :)

How do I get good results? I ask for your help. thank you

---

Thank you verymuch

When converting to Excel, a new empty column was created.

```
test

a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5


dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
df = pd.read_excel(dir_path + '/import/sample.xlsx', header=0)
headers = [list(df.columns), list(df.columns), list(df.columns)]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(headers)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(dir_path + '/export/sample.xlsx', options={'strings_to_urls': False}, )
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='result')
writer.save()

result

    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y
                                <<<<---- empty row  ---->>>>                                                    0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
2   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
3   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
```

I tried to get rid of it but failed.

```
df = df[df['a'] != ""]
```

Comment: It is [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6618) and possible solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372993/pandas-dataframe-with-2-rows-header-and-export-to-csv/45581984#45581984)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns] * 3)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E
   A  B  C  D  E
   A  B  C  D  E
0  a  b  c  d  e
1  a  b  c  d  e
2  a  b  c  d  e
```

If need custom `MultiIndex`:

```
L = [list('abcde'), list('fghij'), list('klmno')]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(L)
print (df)
   a  b  c  d  e
   f  g  h  i  j
   k  l  m  n  o
0  a  b  c  d  e
1  a  b  c  d  e
2  a  b  c  d  e
```

Also is possible use next 2 functions for create `MultiIndex`:

- [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html)
- [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html)

EDIT:

Empty row is [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6618) and solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45581984/2901002):

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("file1.xlsx")
headers = pd.DataFrame(df.columns.tolist()).T
headers.to_excel(writer, header=False, index=False)
df.columns = pd.Index(range(len(df.columns)))  
df.to_excel( writer, header=False, index=False, startrow=len(headers))
writer.save()
```

Comment: @susim -  I just test it `df.to_excel('file1.xlsx')` and it working nice.

Comment: thank you very much!! Newly added. Could you confirm it?.

Comment: @susim - You are welcome. Please dont forget accept and upvote solution. Thanks.