# Parsing multiple values from a file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, parsing, io

The file is like this:

```
1 118 1
1 285 3
...
39861 27196 5
```

So, I would like to parse the file by storing the numbers in variables, since I know apriori that every line contains three integers<sup>*</sup>, how should I do it?

---

Here is my attempt:

```
f = open(fname, 'r')
no_of_headers = 3
for i, line in enumerate(f, no_of_headers):
  print line
```

Here instead of reading into line, it should be modified to read to a, b and c, since we know that every line has three numbers!

---

*<sub>Like `sstream` in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)</sub>

Comment: Related [Skip first couple of lines while reading lines in Python file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9578580) and [How can I write a csv file with multiple header lines with pandas to\_csv()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22356746)

Comment: @BhargavRao, I can't use Pandas :/ The first link is nice, but I want to read the first three lines, not just skip them! Thanks though :)

Comment: Did you read the other answers in the first link? As you are using readlines, a couple of the answers are valid and helpful if you try to use the slice syntax there. Alternatively the `enumerate` answer is also helpful there.

Comment: @BhargavRao, I am currently doing so, yeap the `enumerate` should come in handy. I will update my question with a better attempt, if any. As for readlines, it's a not a must, so if there is another way, bring it on..people :)

Comment: @BhargavRao thank you very much for the links. I could narrow down the question now, *discarding the part that your suggestion solved*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Python's (limited) pattern recognition syntax:

```
for i, line in enumerate(f, no_of_headers):
    a,b,c = line.strip().split() # splits the line by whitespace
```

This assigns each element of the split line to `a`, `b`, `c` respectively. Since each line contains exactly three elements, `a` is mapped to the first element, `b` to the second, and `c` to the third.